# Showing data from 2 models in a grid with Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm trying to select data from two tables and show that data in a paginated grid view. The problem is that Yii is joining the data with a SQL join (because I told it to do it) and because of that it's not showing the correct number of items per page.

To make in clear, I'm selecting from `topics` and `messages_in_topics`, and I'm joining then with

`$criteria->together = true;`

This makes MySQL to return a row for each message (and the related topics). Example:

```
id_topic    topic    id_messages    message

1           topic1   1              message1_in_topic1
1           topic1   2              message2_in_topic1
1           topic1   3              message3_in_topic1
2           topic2   4              message1_in_topic2
2           topic2   5              message2_in_topic2
```

There are only 2 topics, but Yii's paginator *thinks* there are 5.

The fastest way to "fix" this is grouping by the id_topic field, anyways, I can't do that because there's a where condition which searches with the `like` statement.

Thank you

EDIT:

Here's my action code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;

$get_s = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('s', '');
if( $get_s ){
    $criteria->compare("topic_title", $get_s, true);
    $criteria->compare("message_text", $get_s, true, 'OR');
}

$criteria->with = array('messages');
$criteria->addCondition(array( ......  )); <--- some rules like if the topic is validated...

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Topics', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'pagination=>array('pageSize'=>15)
));
```

Comment: `$criteria->togheter = true;` - That is just a typo... right?

Comment: So, it searches `m.message like '%something%'`?

Comment: @Snivs yes, it does. It also searches in the topic's title, but that field is already selected, so it's not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what happens there is that the information being displayed is in regard to your messages. The repeated topic values are because these topics are the corresponding related data to the message.

You could try to tell your query to use GROUP BY in the results...

```
SELECT t.id_topic, t.topic, COUNT(m.id_messages)
  FROM topics t LEFT JOIN messages m ON t.id_topic = m.id_topic
GROUP BY t.id_topic
```

This way, more or less, you can display the count of messages-per-topic.
I could help you more if you'd show us your SQL.

**EDIT**: After seeing your code, here is my guess:
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;

```
$get_s = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('s', '');
if( $get_s ){
    $criteria->compare("topic_title", $get_s, true);
    $criteria->compare("message_text", $get_s, true, 'OR');
}

$criteria->with = array('messages');
$criteria->addCondition(array( ......  )); <--- some rules like if the topic is validated...

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Topics', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'pagination=>array('pageSize'=>15)
));
```

You can make sure the query isn't complicated by yii's formatting by pouring it using only three basic properties of CDbCriteria:

1. **$criteria->select** is exactly the list of columns you want to select.
2. **$criteria->condition** is exactly the WHERE condition, I honestly prefer using a string to an array, since using the string allows me to use the exact condition I put in here.
3. **$criteria->join** is attached immediately after the $model->tableName() you specify in the CActiveDataProvider constructor.
4. **$criteria->group** is added at the end of the query, you just need to specify the grouping column.

Also, You can also make sure to set these properties directly, so you actually descompose your query into the CDbCriteria object. For instance:

```
SELECT t.id_topic, t.topic, COUNT(m.id_messages)
  FROM topics t LEFT JOIN messages m ON t.id_topic = m.id_topic
GROUP BY t.id_topic
```

would be like this

```
/*1*/ $criteria->select = 't.id_topic, t.topic, COUNT(m.id_messages)';
/*2*/ $criteria->condition = 't.topic_title LIKE %'.$get_s.'% OR ...';/* add your conditions here*/
/*3*/ $criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN messages m ON t.id_topic = m.id_topic'; //Full join statement here, including the nature of the join.
/*4*/ $criteria->group = 't.id_topic';
```

**IMPORTANT**: take into account that since you pass your `Topics` classname to the `CActiveDataProvider` constructor, the table under `Topics` will be known as `t`. Any other tables must be specified as well (Pretty much like `messages m` or `messages AS m`)in the join condition otherwise you might get a `column xxxx is ambiguous` warning.

Don't pass out the chance of giving an eye to [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) and [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) for any questions you might have.

Comment: Thank you, I already know what's the problem :) Anyways, I'm not using plain SQL but Yii's CActiveDataProvider. If I can't find a way of doing it just with what Yii offers, I'll write a plain SQL select.

Comment: So, is your problem solved? If not, you could tell me more and display your CActiveDataProvider code. Yii isn't iron-made and always has a way to help you build your custom SQL Queries using [CDbCriteria](http://example.com). Again, if you need anymore help, that's what we're here for.

Comment: Sorry, I meant [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria)

Comment: You could also try an extended version of the existing search() method in your model which will help you trim down/group your data after your where condition. So, in your first query you would get the same results you have (with your where condition) and in your second query you would group these results before returning the CActiveDataProvider object..

Comment: I forgot to mention you, @Snivs , so you probably didn't read this.

Comment: Did you try creating a custom search()? in there you can create the CActiveDataProvider you need using the CDbCriteria you want..

Comment: Of Course, [CGridView, CListView and CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/381/cgridview-clistview-and-cactivedataprovider/) here you can find some documentation on how CGridView works behind the scenes.

Comment: thank you for the code, anyways, there's a problem with it. If I use group I won't be able to search in the messages text (as the group will shrink the results to a single row with the topic and only 1 message).

Comment: You can try to use a nested query to search by message text first (in the inner query) and then group by later or narrowing the results further in the outer query, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the paginator, it is you query.  If you run the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM topics as t
INNER JOIN messages_in_topics as mt
    ON mt.topics_id = t.id
INNER JOIN messages as m
    ON m.id = mt.messages_id
```

You will get 5 results, as show in your example above.

So more importantly, what are you trying to do?

Also, your table shows a MANY_MANY relationship (message1 has 2 topics, topic1 has 3 messages), is your database set up the right way, and are your model relations configured accordingly?

Are you trying to show ALL messages in each topic on a single line?

Are you trying to show ALL topics and list each message with that topic?

Assuming you have relations set up correctly, you can just use: `$messages=$topics->messages;` and get an array with all the messages listed.

Conversely, you can do `$topics=$messages->topics;` to get the topics.

Comment: I'm trying to show a list of all topics and the number of messages each topic has. The SQL select that Snivs wrote should work fine, but I don't know how to make Yii generate an equivalent SQL query. (I'm aiming at not using plain queries but the tools that Yii has for that)